# how to create separate box for each category in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, components, box

I am creating a employee bio data page, for this i have 4 to 5 categories e.g. Personal data, family info, skills, employee history.

my output should be like this
[image]

for all categories, how i can create it in flutter.

i have done this

[image]

and want to convert it to like above design.

---------------EDITED QUESTION--------------------------------

I did the below code but it is not meeting my requirement.

```
 Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5,50, 0),
           child:Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent,width: 100) 
                   
            ),
            child:Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5,50, 0),
            child: TextField(
              
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
            ),
            
           ))
```

here is its output

[image]

please help if anyone know the name of widget or how to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this layout by using `Stack`, `Containers` and `Column`

```
Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _addressController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter Address",
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.home,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      color: Colors.grey),
                                  enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _addressController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter Address",
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.home,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      color: Colors.grey),
                                  enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _addressController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter Address",
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.home,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      color: Colors.grey),
                                  enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _addressController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter Address",
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.home,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      color: Colors.grey),
                                  enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Text(
                                  'Submit',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    BorderSide(
                                        width: 2, color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  foregroundColor:
                                      MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                          Colors.black),
                                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 2, horizontal: 30)),
                                  textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        left: 30,
                        top: 10,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 3,
                            vertical: 2,
                          ),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Text(
                            'Personal Data',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

[image: Output:]

Comment: please check my required output, i edited my question.

Comment: Please check it now @TimeToCode.  answer updated.

Comment: YESS! this is what i want! thank you @Roshini :)

Comment: Happy Coding!! @TimeToCode

Answer (score 0):

bro take a container giver border to container like this

```
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
  ),
```

after that take inputfield and make this field border none like this

```
borde:InputBorder.none
```

so you can easily do that by this way

Comment: can i add more than one textbox using this?